# Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity error with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, .net-standard

I'm attempting to build a Xamarin iOS app using .NET Standard 2.0 dependencies. One of these dependencies includes a reference to the `System.Reflection.Emit 4.3.0` NuGet package.
This causes a build error when the iOS app is built, as this dll conflicts with the reference facade for `System.Reflection.Emit`:

> CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\ndesl.nuget\packages\system.reflection.emit\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Reflection.Emit.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Anyone knows how to deal with this?
Shouldn't those assemblies be recognised as 2 versions of the same assembly?

Attempting to specify a binding redirect in app.config doesn't help. I'm using the latest versions of Xamarin and VS2017.

A minimal project exhibiting the issue can be found here: https://github.com/nicodeslandes/ReflectionEmitBuildIssue

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  We are hitting this exact same issue and using PackageReference and the new project templates hasn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @Ensunder take a look at ossentoo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641285/3411592)

Answer (score 3):

Convert your iOS project to use `PackageReference` in the csproj file instead of packages.config. See [Issues with .NET Standard 2.0 with .NET Framework & NuGet](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31) on dotnet/announcements GitHub and [Using Xamarin Forms with .NET Standard – VS 2017 Edition](https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/) for more information.

Comment: This issue might happen to any other assembly, I guess. In my case it was `System.Reactive.Linq`. But the conversion to PackageReference solved the issue.

Comment: There is a PowerShell script I've found for the auto conversion: https://gist.github.com/a4099181/074a6c3dd524ea0d343382137492399c

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I was facing same issue on MAC version of visual studio but hopefully this will work fine for you as well.

**Solution:** After spending few hours I found a workaround [here](https://www.e-learn.cn/content/wangluowenzhang/757556) in answer no. 2.

Simply delete System.Reflection.Emit.dll at following path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add my answer to the list. What resolved it for me was removing the hint path in the csproj file. Once I did that everything built and ran fine.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, although it was for other `System` assemblies